# pandas Dataframe create new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this snippet of the code working with pandas dataframe, i am trying to use the apply function to create a new column called STDEV_TV but i keep running into this error all the columns i am working with are type float

```
TypeError: ("'float' object is not iterable", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Can someone help me understand why i keep getting this error

```
def sigma(df):
    val = df.volume2Sum / df.volumeSum - df.vwap * df.vwap
    return math.sqrt(max(val))


df['STDEV_TV'] = df.apply(sigma, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (5, 3)),
                  columns=['volume2Sum', 'volumeSum', 'vwap'])

def sigma(df):
    val = df.volume2Sum / df.volumeSum - df.vwap * df.vwap
    return math.sqrt(val) if val >= 0 else val

df['STDEV_TV'] = df.apply(sigma, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   volume2Sum  volumeSum  vwap   STDEV_TV
0           4          5     8 -63.200000
1           2          8     4 -15.750000
2           3          3     3  -8.000000
3           8          3     4 -13.333333
4           4          2     3  -7.000000
```

Comment: HEY the return statement got this error ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Update your post with the output of `df.head(10)` please.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return math.sqrt(max(val))
```

to

```
return math.sqrt(max(val)) if isinstance(val, pd.Series) else (math.sqrt(val) if val >= 0 else val)
```

`max()` iterates over an iterable and find the maximum value. The problem here is since you're applying `sigma` to every row, local variable `val` is a float, not a list, so what you have similar to `max(1.3)`.

Comment: i get at TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'> when i do that but i need to find the max in the val variable

Comment: ```def sigma_tradingview(x):
    val = x.V2SUM / x.VOLUME_SUM - x.VWAP * x.VWAP
    # kind of a hack to mimic that tv max() function
    if val <= 0:
        val = 0
    return math.sqrt(val)

df['STDEV_TV'] = df.apply(sigma_tradingview, axis=1)``` this is the code that i was trying to replicate

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply sigma to each set of values not the whole DataFrame.
I would use a lambda function, eg:

```
def sigma(volume2Sum, volumeSum, vwap):
    val = volume2Sum / volumeSum - vwap * vwap
    return math.sqrt(val)


df['STDEV_TV'] = df.apply(lambda x: sigma(x.volume2Sum, x.volumeSum, x.vwap), axis=1)
```

That should put val into the STDEV_TV column and you can find the max value separately.
Take care you not to take the squareroot of a negative number.

Comment: still getting this error TypeError: ("'float' object is not iterable", 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Hey check out @Corralien it seems to be working with that

Answer (score 0):

You function sigma gives you one number as a result. Because, the first step you find the maximum:

```
max(val)
```

and it's only the one number...
After that you try uses you function for data series.
You should use in your code this last string:

```
df['STDEV_TV'] = sigma(df)
```

It will be working